# Assigning a value to a property by reference to a lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

I have 2 objects (a DTO and a Entry Framework Object) and I want to update the EF Entity if the corresponding value in the DTO is different.  I envisage it would be done like this:
`UpdateIfDifferent(dtoObject, x => x.MailStatus, efObject, r => r.MailStatus);
 UpdateIfDifferent(dtoObject, x => x.WebStatus, efObject, r => r.WebStatus);`

```
private void UpdateIfDifferent<TOriginal, TOriginalProperty, TUpdated, TUpdatedProperty>
  (TOriginal original, Expression<Func<TOriginal, TOriginalProperty>> originalProperty, 
TUpdated updated, Expression<Func<TUpdated, TUpdatedProperty>> updatedProperty)
  {
      if (!originalProperty.Compile()(original).Equals(updatedProperty.Compile()(updated)))  {
        // how do I assign back to original from updated?
        }
      }
    }
```

I believe the following should work but I do not know how I can assign the value back to the efObject.  Can anybody clue me in please?

Comment: You need to get `MemberExpression` from `originalProperty.Body`, then get `PropertyInfo`, and then you can call Get\SetValue methods passing your original\updated entities

Comment: Jonathan, I really believe you don't get much help from introducing this method. Its signature is confusing and the implementation is just an "if" and an assignment. If I were you I would reconsider my approach and refactor my code to remove this method completely. A one-line if and an assignment instead of a method call would in my opinion make the code much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
public static void Main()       
{
    var original = new TestEntity();
    original.Name = "test";

    var dto = new TestDTO();
    dto.FirstName = "New Value";

    UpdateIfDifferent(original, o => o.Name, dto, d => d.FirstName);

    Console.WriteLine(original.Name);
}

private static void UpdateIfDifferent<TOriginal, TOriginalProperty, TUpdated, TUpdatedProperty>
    (TOriginal original, Expression<Func<TOriginal, TOriginalProperty>> originalProperty, 
        TUpdated updated, Expression<Func<TUpdated, TUpdatedProperty>> updatedProperty)
{
  if (!originalProperty.Compile()(original).Equals(updatedProperty.Compile()(updated)))  
  {

        var updatedMember = (updatedProperty.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
        var updatedValue = updatedMember.GetValue(updated);

        var member = (originalProperty.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
        member.SetValue(original, updatedValue);

    }
}

public class TestEntity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class TestDTO
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

Here is a working sample on DotNetFiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/k1qLZH

This sample is just for property and member access. So if your expression will have another signature like method,sub property, field access then this code will fail.

Another approach without lambda compilation that takes some time might be:

```
private static void UpdateIfDifferent<TOriginal, TOriginalProperty, TUpdated, TUpdatedProperty>
    (TOriginal original, Expression<Func<TOriginal, TOriginalProperty>> originalProperty, 
        TUpdated updated, Expression<Func<TUpdated, TUpdatedProperty>> updatedProperty)
{

    var updatedMember = (updatedProperty.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
    var updatedValue = updatedMember.GetValue(updated);

    var originalMember = (originalProperty.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
    var originalValue = originalMember.GetValue(original);

    if (!object.Equals(updatedValue, originalValue))
        originalMember.SetValue(original, updatedValue);

}
```

Comment: While this possibly works, it looks ugly as hell. Generics with four (sic!) parameters and reflection in one method that looks like nothing but a code smell. And the problem is not the solution, it is the original signature of the method that makes it so bad.